# facebook permission to post to wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am looking for some scriptes but cant find good one :(

```
 FB.ui({
    method: 'permissions.request',
    perms: 'user_website',
    display: 'popup'
    },function(response) {
        alert(response.toSource());
        if (response && response.perms) {
            alert('Permissions granted: '+response.perms);
        } else if (!response.perms){
            alert('User did not authorize permission(s).');
        }
});
```

Comment: Is this throwing an error? Are you trying to get permissions or post to the wall?

Comment: I didn't get your question clearly, Do you want ability that current logged in user can post any status on their wall or your app can post any comment on their user's wall or what ?